# How can I get shell access on my almost dead phone

Tags: adb, shell

My phone broke, so I have been messing with it and from the errors I can see, it looks like all the system folders are missing. /system /data etc.

I saw a YT video where the guy used ADB shell to gain access then just ran some cd commands to create the missing directories (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-LZvVLEC5o)

adb shell isn't working for me. Currently, I have 'Philz Touch 5' running and I have a working Odin connection.

How can I restore an empty file system?

thanks!

Comment: By [flashing a ROM](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom-flashing/info). `/system` and `/data` are not just directories you've got to create, but entire mount points. If there's no `/system`, you can no longer boot the device as it has no operating system (`/recovery` is a separate system). So use Odin to flash a ROM.

Answer (score 0):

if you can go in recovery mode, you can also go in download mode.
if you use odin, i guess you have a samsung device.
Normally push togheter power button, home button, volume - button
turn any samsung mobile in donwload mode.
downlaod an official ROM from http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/
and flash it with odin.